# (Python, Selenium WD) How to automate these actions - cycle or function?

Tags: python, function, selenium, cycle

How to automate these actions - cycle or function?

```
wd.find_element_by_link_text("Logotype").click()
assert "Logotype" in wd.title
wd.find_element_by_link_text("Catalog").click()
assert "Catalog" in wd.title
wd.find_element_by_link_text("Product Groups").click()
assert "Product Groups" in wd.title
wd.find_element_by_link_text("Option Groups").click()
assert "Option Groups" in wd.title
```

Comment: Are you using pytest? Sometimes test code is more readable and useful when you write it explicitly like in your question instead of refactoring it. For  longer sequences of similar test cases you can use pytest's paremetrized tests, which results in more helpful error messages than what you get with a regular for-loop. http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you'll do with a `for` loop. All you need do is put the strings in a list:

```
lst = ["Logotype", "Catalog", "Product Groups", "Option Groups"]

for item in lst:
    wd.find_element_by_link_text(item).click()
    assert item in wd.title
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply